# Spinner is not updating

Tags: android, kotlin, view, spinner

I have a spinner that has to be dynamically populated. When my call from the API returns data, my presenter calls the view and sets my data on it. At this point I am expecting that my spinner is updated and shows my values but that does not happen. Here's my view:

```
class MyCustomView(
    private val fragmentContext: Context,
    private val fragment: ContainerFragment
) : ICustomView, FrameLayout(fragmentContext) {

    init {
        View.inflate(context, R.layout.my_custom_view, this)

        val activity = fragment.activity as AppCompatActivity
        activity.setSupportActionBar(my_toolbar)
    }

    override fun getView(): View {
        return this
    }

    override fun setData(uiModel: UiModel) {
        val adapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, uiModel.data)
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        catalogue_volume_size_spinner.adapter = adapter
    }
}
```

If I do the same but inside the constructor's `init` block it works (for unknown reason). The issue is that I don't have my data ready at the construction time. Eveything else works as expect but not this spinner.

Comment: Notify after setting the spinner adapter ?

Comment: Tried, doesn't work.

Comment: You are certain you uiModel.data has valid items?

Comment: @dominicoder yes. I've tried many things, everything is correct. Data is there, just a simple list of strings. Even if I create a static list of data after `init` block it doesn't work.

Comment: Have you stepped through the source code to see what happens when you set the data on init vs after the request? Do you have an example project that reproduces the issue you can share? I can investigate if you do.

Comment: @dominicoder I did. The data is there, and it's passed around as expected. It seems that the UI is not updated though. For some reason, any custom View that extends any Layout or View doesn't behave well. I have switched to a full Fragment but I'm still investigating this issue.

Comment: Try setting `setWillNotDraw` to `false` - ViewGroups like FrameLayout set it to true by default so it could be that you views are failing to draw after being updated.